# Having trouble configuring sphinx search

Tags: installation, sphinx

I downloaded sphinx 0.9.9 to my ubuntu 10.4 machine.

I ran `cd ~/sphinx-0.9.9` then `./configure`, then `make` then `make install`.

Make install gave me errors so I ran `sudo make install` and then there were no errors.

I am going through the documentation. I am at *[2.6. Quick Sphinx usage tour](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/manual-0.9.9.html#quick-tour)*.

It says:

> All the example commands below assume that you installed Sphinx in /usr/local/sphinx, so searchd can be found in /usr/local/sphinx/bin/searchd.

I do have `/usr/local/sphinx` but there is no `bin` folder in it, just `etc` and `var`.

It then also says:

> there's example.sql sample data file to populate that table with a few documents for testing purposes:
>
> $ mysql -u test < /usr/local/sphinx/etc/example.sql

but inside my `/usr/local/sphinx/etc/` folder there is only one file: `sphinx.conf`

and according to the docs that file shouldnt event exist yet, it should be `sphinx.conf.dist`

---

I tried to install sphinx 6 months ago and gave up. I am only revisiting it now, so maybe there is a chance I screwed something up then that is giving me problems now. Is there a way to remove everything sphinx so I can try again fresh? Or does anyone have any other ideas what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

You might try installing the [package version](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/sphinxsearch) of sphinx; it's slightly older, but should work as well. As far as compiling problems, you might check the [SphinxSearch forum](http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/forum.html?id=1).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have installation issue here.
The output of make command will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest reinstalling sphinx, just delete the folder/or run sudo make uninstall, where you had installed the sphinx, and then following these steps to reinstall sphinx

1. Update and Grab dependencies. Run these commands in order to get the files you need to install Sphinx.

   - sudo apt-get update
   - sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
   - sudo apt-get install build-essential
   - sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient15-dev
2. Download source, Untar and prep. Here's where it gets a bit complicated. You'll need to extract the source, change into the directory and configure Sphinx. Do that with these commands.

   - tar xvzf sphinx-0.9.8.1.tar.gz
   - cd sphinx-0.9.8.1/
   - ./configure --with-mysql-includes=/usr/include/mysql --with-mysql-libs=/usr/lib/mysql
3. Make and Install Sphinx

   - make
   - sudo make install